# Image handling in WPF not thread safe?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, image

I am creating a Window in a different thread that's marked STA this window has a few controls and images.

I than go and close this window and open another window in the main UI Thread in this I have a print dialog and use the following code to get a `FixedDocumentSequence`:

```
var tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
File.Delete(tempFileName);

using (var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempFileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite, CompressionOption.NotCompressed))
{
    var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);

    writer.Write(this.DocumentPaginator);
}

using (var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempFileName, FileAccess.Read, CompressionOption.NotCompressed))
{
    var xpsDoc = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    return xpsDoc;
}
```

On the line:

```
writer.Write(this.DocumentPaginator);
```

I am getting a **InvalidOperationException** from a internal call to **VerifyAccess**, this is the StackTrace:

```
bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
bei System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.get_IsDownloading()
bei System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.get_IsDownloading()
bei System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.FreezeCore(Boolean isChecking)
bei System.Windows.Freezable.Freeze(Boolean isChecking)
bei System.Windows.PropertyMetadata.DefaultFreezeValueCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, EntryIndex entryIndex, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean isChecking)
bei System.Windows.Freezable.FreezeCore(Boolean isChecking)
bei System.Windows.Media.Animation.Animatable.FreezeCore(Boolean isChecking)
bei System.Windows.Freezable.Freeze()
bei System.Windows.Media.DrawingDrawingContext.DrawImage(ImageSource imageSource, Rect rectangle, AnimationClock rectangleAnimations)
bei System.Windows.Media.DrawingDrawingContext.DrawImage(ImageSource imageSource, Rect rectangle)
bei System.Windows.Media.DrawingContextDrawingContextWalker.DrawImage(ImageSource imageSource, Rect rectangle)
bei System.Windows.Media.RenderData.BaseValueDrawingContextWalk(DrawingContextWalker ctx)
bei System.Windows.Media.DrawingServices.DrawingGroupFromRenderData(RenderData renderData)
bei System.Windows.UIElement.GetDrawing()
bei System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(Visual reference)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.VisualTreeFlattener.StartVisual(Visual visual)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachVisualSerializer.SerializeTree(Visual visual, XmlWriter resWriter, XmlWriter bodyWriter)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachVisualSerializer.SerializeObject(Object serializedObject)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.DocumentPageSerializer.SerializeChild(Visual child, SerializableObjectContext parentContext)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.DocumentPageSerializer.PersistObjectData(SerializableObjectContext serializableObjectContext)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.ReachSerializer.SerializeObject(Object serializedObject)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.DocumentPageSerializer.SerializeObject(Object serializedObject)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.DocumentPaginatorSerializer.PersistObjectData(SerializableObjectContext serializableObjectContext)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.DocumentPaginatorSerializer.SerializeObject(Object serializedObject)
bei System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.XpsSerializationManager.SaveAsXaml(Object serializedObject)
bei System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter.SaveAsXaml(Object serializedObject, Boolean isSync)
bei System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter.Write(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator)
```

Since the StackTrace does some call to `BitmapSource/BitmapDecoder`, I thought about trying to remove the Images and set the Source of the in-place Image controls to null

```
<Image Source={x:Null} />
```

After I did this with all of my Images my code was running smoothly and no more exception was firing.

I tried to make a customimage to solve this problem with the following:

```
public class CustomImage : Image
{
    public CustomImage()
    {
        this.Loaded += CustomImage_Loaded;
        this.SourceUpdated += CustomImage_SourceUpdated;
    }

    private void CustomImage_SourceUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        FreezeSource();
    }

    private void CustomImage_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FreezeSource();
    }

    private void FreezeSource()
    {
        if (this.Source == null)
            return;

        var freeze = this.Source as Freezable;
        if (freeze != null && freeze.CanFreeze && !freeze.IsFrozen)
            freeze.Freeze();
    }
}
```

But I am still getting the error.
Preferable I am searching for a solution that works on all images in my WPF application.

*Hope I made my self clear, since this is rather odd to explain with the 2 threads and a random exception at some point.*

**Edit:**
After some further testing I am now able to present to you a reproducible application with the problem at hand, hope its clearer with this.

You need 3 windows, 1 folder and 1 image.
In my case its
MainWindow.xaml
Window1.xaml
Window2.xaml

Images is the name of the folder, and in there is an image called "plus.png".

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="0,0,0,5"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Open Window 1" Click="OpenWindowInNewThread" />
    <Button Content="Open Window 2" Click="OpenWindowInSameThread" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
private void OpenWindowInNewThread(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        var x = new Window1();
        x.Closed += (s, ec) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

        x.Show();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.IsBackground = true;
    th.Start();
}

private void OpenWindowInSameThread(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = new Window2();
    x.Show();
}
```

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource PlusToggleButton}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs:**
*No Code in there just constructor...*

**Window2.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource PlusToggleButton}" />
    <Button Content="Print Me" Click="Print"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**Window2.xaml.cs:**

```
public void Print(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    pd.PrintVisual(this, "HelloWorld");
}
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PlusToggleButton"
                    TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Image Name="Image"
            Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/plus.png"
            Stretch="None" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. In the MainWindow click on the button saying "Open Window 1".
2. A window will popup in a second UI-Thread, close this Window.
3. Click the button saying "Open Window 2"
4. A window will popup in the main UI-Thread
5. Hit the button saying "Print Me", application should crash

Hope its now easier to help me out.

**Edit2:**

Added the missing code part, sorry about this mistake.

Another info that might help solve the problem is that when you click the buttons in reversed order - first Window 2 and than Window 1 - and than go try to print no exception will fire, so I still believe that its some image caching problem, that when the image first gets loaded into main UI-Thread printing works if not it will fail.

Comment: You might try to freeze the original images in the first place. Instead of loading them from an Uri you would manually retrieve them from the web (e.g.by a WebClient) and initialize a BitmapImage from a MemoryStream that contains the downloaded buffer. You could then immediately freeze them after creating the BitmapImage. You may of course also do this in yet another thread.

Comment: How can I freeze the original images? The only thing I do is I specify the image in XAML with <Image Source="..\Images\foo.jpg" />, I don't use any WebClient or load the images in a async way, I just merely have a Window in a separate thread that displays an image, once I close that window and go back to the main UI-Thread and try to print the same image it crashes. Do I remove the Images with {x:Null} everything works.

Comment: @Clemens forgot the [at] on my last comment, please have a look at my message on this question

Comment: A quick check here shows that images loaded from local file Uris are already frozen.

Comment: @Clemens please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @RandRandom there is no Click handler, Print, for the Print Me button

Comment: @NETscape sorry my mistake, I will update the post tomorrow dont have the code at hand right now, but its basically an empty documentpaginator that prints the window. Please either try yourself or come back tomorrow.

Comment: @RandRandom I'll be here tomorrow :)

Comment: @NETscape sorry for the wait, its even simpler code than I originally had a simple .PrintVisual causes the crash,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an UI object that was created by `Window1` on `Window2`.

Essentially, parts of `ControlTemplate` are shared between threads, which should not happen (namely `BitmapImage`, as I've read from your callstack).

You can explictly tell that no sharing:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PlusToggleButton"
                    TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
                    x:Shared="False">
```

Comment: Please please tell that this is a lie, please dont say that all I need to do is set an boolean and everything is fine... And I kept banging my head against the table for almost a week... Gona test it right soonish...

Comment: Works fine, gona read into this topic if I have further questions I will come back. Currently I wonder about performance issues if I just randomly put x:Shared="false" on every control I have?!?

Comment: I read now the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx and I dont really get why the exception doesnt come upon opening the Window 2?!? If I understood it correctly it should happen, because the Window 2 also access the same resource and build the button/image so why does only the printing fire the exception?!? Do you have any explanation for it?

Comment: @RandRandom: as far I can tell, the  `BitmapImage` is cached by default for performance reasons. It sounds to me like `Window2` does not hit `VerifyAccess()` when **displaying** the `BitmapImage`, but only when it wants to actually print it.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa you should add your last comment to the answer.  I have found the same.

Answer (score 3):

The exception suggests that you are trying to access a control (essentially a class derived from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject(v=vs.110).aspx)) outside the thread that created it!

It's difficult to suggest a code fix based on your explanation of threads. But a simple rule would be to make sure that you create a UI thread agnostic control in UI thread, and also do the same while accessing properties of such control.

looking at the code

```
this.DocumentPaginator
```

This property accessor seems to be violating thread access (which means, this propery is being accessed by a thread which did not create it).

You can use following code to run property accessors on UI thread (and you will also need to make sure that such object is created on UI thread)

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
  new Action(() => {
//Your code/method name here
}
));
```

If the concept is new for you, worth reading this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) page

Here is MSDN reference for [VerifyAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.verifyaccess(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your "information". I am afraid to tell you but all you said is something I know already. That's also the first thing I tried wrapping the print method inside a Dispatcher Invoke. I also check what CheckAccess returned and it always returned true, for ALL elements that I could find in a recursive way in the VisualTree. After I removed the image's source with {x:Null} everything works just fine, so my hint was that WPF loads the image in the second STA thread and the main UI Thread than tries to load it from Cache and there for the exception. That's why I tried my above approach.

Comment: And I do not access any Image in code, or handle them in any way the only thing that happens is that I display them in the UI or print them, all I do is in my XAML <Image Source="..\Images\foo.jpg" />, and as I mentioned once I change it to <Image Source="{x:Null}" /> everything is fine.

Answer (score -2):

With current edits, this issue is most certainly because of "Print", Click handler, Print me button. I tried this code in a new project and I can't make it crash, so the error is most likely in Print function.

Comment: You couldnt make it crash, because I forgot to add the Print Event, its now included please have a look again, would appreciate it.